# NgSwitch or ComponentFactoryResolver?

Tags: angular

I'm writing an app that lists some users and displays an information page when a user is clicked. The users are of different types (about 20 types) and the details page differs for each user type in layout and functionality.

I have a main `DetailsComponent` and 20 specific components (`Type1DetailsComponent`, `Type2DetailsComponent`, etc.) that must be displayed inside the main `DetailsComponent`.

I thought of two ways to implement this:

1. Use `NgSwitch` in the `DetailsComponent` to choose the specific component
2. Use `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` to create the specific component needed and display it inside `DetailsComponent`

The first method requires that all `SpecificDetailsComponent`s be listed in the `NgSwitch`, reducing scalability.

The second method seems better, but it has a few drawbacks:

- a target element is needed to place the dynamically created component. The new component cannot replace the target element, but is placed after it. That looks like clutter.
- @Input and @Output are not automatically set by Angular when creating the components.

Is there anything I can do to improve the second method?

Are there any better methods of achieving the goal?

Answer (score 1):

The target element does get replaced I believe, but either way it's just one errant element if it doesn't. The CFR is going to be ~50% faster even if the components are complicated I think.